# How to get selected row in slickgrid from outside slickgrid event

Tags: row, slickgrid

My rows in slickgrid are selected (highlighted) mainly using the arrow keys, but mouse selection is allowed.  I have a button outside of the slickgrid, which, when pressed, is to get the row that is highlighted (selected) in the slickgrid. There is no event occurring in slickgrid after the selection (highlighting) has been made (eg grid.onClick, grid.onKeyDown, etc) so I have no idea on how to find the row that is highlighted (selected), specifically when clicking on a button.  Could an event be programmatically generated into slickgrid to do this? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume that you're not using the dedicated plugin for that which is `slick.checkboxselectcolumn` and `slick.rowselectionmodel.js` and you can see this [Example](http://6pac.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html) and from that you'll get access to `onSelectedRowsChanged` event and if you choose to make it single click then clicking anywhere on the row will trigger the event (if however you're using multiple row selection then it will only trigger from the left column checkboxes)

```js
import '../plugins/slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js';
import '../plugins/slick.rowselectionmodel.js';

grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({selectActiveRow: false}));
grid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector2);

grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function (e, args) {
  // debugging to see the active row in response to questions
  // active row has no correlation to the selected rows
  // it will remain null until a row is clicked and made active
  // selecting and deselecting rows via checkboxes will not change the active row
  var rtn = args.grid.getActiveCell();
  var x = args.rows;
});
```

From the row indexes, there's multiple way to retrieve the associated item object, in my case I use SlickGrid DataView and I retrieve it with the following

```js
for (const row of args.rows) {
  const itemObj = dataView.getItem(row);
  // do something
}
```

There's multiple methods for different behavior in SlickGrid and in DataView

```js
// -- DataView --//
/** Get DataView item at specific index */
getItem(index: number) => any;

/** Get an item in the DataView by its Id */
getItemById(id: string | number) => any | null;

/** Get an item in the DataView by its row index */
getItemByIdx(idx: number) => any;

/** Get row index in the DataView by its Id */
getIdxById(id: string | number): number | undefined;
```

```js
// -- SlickGrid --//
/**
 * Returns the databinding item at a given position.
 * @param index Item row index.
 */
getDataItem(rowIndex: number): any;
```

Comment: I found a partial solution.  When the arrow keys are pressed I pull the event and then get the row.  The problem is that because slcikgrid has sorted it, the highlighted row does not correspond to the "real" row in the database.  I solved this problem by searching the database for the correct data, somewhat convoluted and inefficient, but it does work.  I say a partial solution because when data is first loaded into  slickgrid with the top row highlighted, I am unable to get the "real" data that corresponds to this highlighted row at the top.  But I will try your solution.

Comment: update the answer and provided more options to try, I'm a big of SlickGrid DataView and is what I use, there's more methods available too, you should be fine with `dataView.getItem(row);`

Comment: I used Slickgrid because it seemed to have some nice features, but I could never get the dataView to work right.  For this project, the grid is important, but is only a small part, and I do not think I can spare the time to figure all things out.  I have a multi dimensional array (array of arrays) for the data, and coming from C, VB, and dBase programming I found the dataView confusing to implement for this, and not finding much documentation.

Comment: yeah, SlickGrid and the DataView are not very supporting of data that is not an array of objects, with the columns as the object properties. Is there any way to convert your data to that form?